# Calling command from `-c` command line argument doesn't work in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I'm using the [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin.

It has a command(?) `Git!` which executes a command and opens the result in a new buffer.

Example:

```
:Git! diff --cached
```

I have a function which calls this, and does some other things after that.

And I have this command declaration:

```
command! Hello execute ":Git! diff"
```

If I run `:Hello` from within vim, it works as it should. But when I run `vim -c Hello`, it throws this error:

```
Not an editor command :Git! diff
```

How can I do this?

(PS: How can I make this error message to stay until I press ? It appears for about a second and disappears.)

Comment: You can use the `:mes` command to see the message history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Fugitive only defines its commands for buffers whose files are under Git version control. Precisely, the code in `plugin/fugitive.vim` only sets up autocmds that detect files under Git control, and only then defines buffer-local commands.

So at least you need to pass a Git-controlled file to your Vim invocation. If that still doesn't work, try explicitly triggering the detection via

```
:doautocmd User Fugitive
```

Comment: Right. I _was_ running this from a git directory, but passing `.` as the first parameter (`vim . -c Hello`) worked perfectly.